# Highstock navigator style / font

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way to update the font size/color of the dates in the `navigator` in Highstock?

Based on the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator), it doesn't have the usual `style` property. I wanted to decrease the font size of the dates and experiment on the color a bit but HS doesn't seem to have that option.

Comment: According to [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.xAxis) you can set different labels options - navigator's xAxis options are the same standard xAxis.

Answer (score 8):

```
navigator: {
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: '#6D869F',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }
                }
            },
        },
```